# Что означает эта надпись?

Tags: значение-слов

Может быть, вопрос не совсем по адресу, но очень бы хотелось узнать, что означает вот эта надпись, фотографии которой мне часто попадаются в интернете:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я, когда впервые в магазине увидела эту надпись(она располагается над дверью), спросила, что она обозначает, потому что восприняла сначала слово порошок  как обращение. Смешно получилось. Мне пояснили, что при пожаре или угрозе пожара что-то там срабатывает и распыляется порошок. А надпись предупреждает посетителей об этом и предлагает уйти.  В любом случае странная фраза.

Comment: Я бы написал так: "Порошок! Уходи!!!"
И надеюсь на то, что эта надпись станет вполне понятной каждому тогда, когда транспарант начнёт непосредственно действовать в заданной функции: одновременно с распылением порошка (при сигнале "пожар" от соответствующего датчика) включится мигающая подсветка и устрашающий звуковой сигнал. 
В *мирное* же время непонимание семантики и назначения устройства не приводит к фатальным последствиям.

Answer (score 0):

Да,фраза,конечно,странная из-за своей оформленности.Можно было бы написать так "Осторожно,порошок!" по аналогии с "Осторожно,окрашено!" Но опять-таки неясность не исчезает.Дело в том,что вторая фраза широко известна,в отличии от первой.Отсюда - неясность.Даже если фраза будет стилистически и синтактически грамотно оформлена(см.мой пример).

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что это обращение))) И получается что-то вроде "отпусти меня, чудо трава"))) Вообще, они бы могли написать хотя бы "уходите", а не "уходи", тогда не воспринималось бы как обращение к порошку.)))

Comment: Да, так было бы понятнее. Интересно, кто автор фразы?  Или это перевод?

Comment: Я вот тоже не знаю. Но настолько коряво, что действительно похоже на перевод